# Apache - Website timeout after random time ( Fore to restart Apache )

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, timeout, apache2

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have a big problem with my Apache server.

( Now I use Google Translate for message )

For a reason that I do not know yet, randomly, my Apache2 server starts to stop responding (Error 500).

I noticed something when the problem occurs, in the file "error.log", I always find this line:

```
[Mon Aug 14 18:42:39.917495 2017] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 23163] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

After that, I had asked to change the value "MaxRequestWorkers", but it did not change anything, the problem is still there.

I also noticed that generally, when the problem occurs, it is following a strong request sucks the Apache server (Especially
the last, a raw force attack), with these log (access.log):

http://p.hexicans.eu/MMgRunkXQX

In the file "error.log", I also recorded many of these errors:

```
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366861 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22399 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366873 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22401 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366883 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22402 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366890 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22425 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366898 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22428 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366910 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22451 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366923 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22456 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366965 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22460 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366981 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22466 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366990 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22468 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Aug 14 18:28:58.366997 2017] [core:warn] [pid 20916] AH00045: child process 22469 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

I have already spent a lot of time looking for a solution, and so far I have not found it, that's why I'm heading to this forum ^^

My actualy "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf" file :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        ServerLimit              500
        StartServers             10
        MinSpareServers          10
        MaxSpareServers          400
        MaxRequestWorkers        256
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
        KeepAlive                Off
</IfModule>
```

Other information :

- OS : Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Apache : Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- PHP : Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Hum, no ideas ? ^^

Answer (score 0):

The MaxRequestWorkers directive sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be served. Any connection attempts over the MaxRequestWorkers limit will normally be queued, up to a number based on the ListenBacklog directive. Once a child process is freed at the end of a different request, the connection will then be serviced.

MaxRequestWorkers translates into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to serve requests. The default value is 256; to increase it, **you must also raise ServerLimit.**

Comment: Hmm, I've set the "ServerLimit" parameter to 500 ... But how do you calculate "MaxRequestWorkers" against "ServerLimit" ?

Comment: Hmm, no idea .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Earlier, I just noticed something,

The problem occurs only on sites that are not in HTTPS ( And leaves after a few hours ).